# Read a single char using Scanner without removing it from the scanner

Tags: java, character, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a parser and I need to take exactly one char from the input and then change the control flow based on the value of this char,I know that I can do something like this `input.next().charAt(0)`,but if I will do it not only this char but the whole next string will disappear from the scanner and this is not what I want,so is there a way to check the value of the next character without taking it out of the scanner?

Comment: Why not store the result of `input.next()` in a local variable? It seems you are going the wrong way.

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do that makes you think you need this?

Comment: It seems obvious,but this is not the solution for me,because in this case the whole structure of the parser would be broken,the idea is that the parse works only with the scanner object,without using "help" variables

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to process character by character,
you'll want to do something like this:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("");
```

After this, `scanner.next()` will read character by character.

You cannot put data back into a scanner.
But you can wrap a scanner in a custom class to create the illusion of putting stuff back.
For example:

```
class PeekableScanner {

    private final Scanner scanner;
    private String next;

    public PeekableScanner(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
        this.next = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : null;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
    }

    public String next() {
        String current = next;
        next = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : null;
        return current;
    }

    public String peek() {
        return next;
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("hello");
scanner.useDelimiter("");
PeekableScanner peekable = new PeekableScanner(scanner);

while (peekable.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(peekable.peek());
    System.out.println(peekable.next());
}
```

This will print each character twice.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you read from a Scanner the token is used. Thus`input.next().charAt(0)`reads out the token then tells you the character at 0.

Read then store the token as a String.

SubString the charAt(0)

Then subString the rest and use it in your program.